# Swift macOS Application Determine Which Window Appears at Launch

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I am working on a Cocoa macOS Swift project built using Swift 4 and Xcode 9, and I want to achieve the behavior of an application changing the first window that appears based on a UserDefaults variable. I have seen examples of this done in iOS applications, but after testing some of the available code, it seems that in this case the iOS examples do not work for macOS. In my application's delegate, I can check the value of this variable, but how would I efficiently and properly act upon it?

Ideally, if a certain condition is met `Window 2` would appear at launch and `Window 1` would not appear. If that condition is not met, the application would display `Window 1` at launch.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just set them both not to be visible at startup, and then call `makeKeyAndOrderFront` on the correct one in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` based on the defaults key?

Comment: Is the app document-based?

Comment: This application is not document based. If I made them both not visible, then called `makeKeyAndOrderFront` on a window, wouldn't both windows be in memory, and both of their `viewDidLoad` methods be called?